# Amazon RDS Aurora to 'MySQL for Excel', Security (SSL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am considering using AWS Aurora(MySQL) as a store for analytical data. The use case is to allow remote users to connect to the RDS and connect via the MySQL for Excel plugin.

The unencrypted connection works as expected, however enabling SSL as per AWS instructions seems counter-intuitive.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Perhaps it's my lack of understanding of SSL, but the instructions require the downloading of a 'generic' SSL cert from AWS. This certificate is freely available to anyone with an internet connection, surely I would need a unique account-specific SSL certificate to ensure the integrity of the connection?

Hope this question makes sense.

Kind regards